# Postgres COPY - ERROR: row is too big: size 8216, maximum size 8160

Tags: postgresql

I have a GCT file which I am trying to add to Postgres table through this:

```
PGPASSWORD=MyPassword psql -h mydb.abcdef.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U myuser -d mydata -c "\copy TEST_RNASEQ_20180929 FROM '/data/TEST_RNAseq_20180929_trimed.gct' with (format csv,header true, delimiter E'\t');"
```

The table has 1021 columns of type `text`.

This is the error:

```
ERROR:  row is too big: size 8216, maximum size 8160
CONTEXT:  COPY test_rnaseq_20180929, line 9
```

This is 3 lines from the file:

```
chr1_18061_17915_WASH7P_3p  ENSG00000227232.4   1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98214 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99371 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98734 1.00000 1.00000 0.97059 0.98780 1.00000 0.98182 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.93333 0.98077 1.00000 0.98611 1.00000 1.00000 0.98551 0.98592 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97436 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99432 1.00000 1.00000 0.99160 1.00000 0.98000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98182 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.96970 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98000 0.99020 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97692 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97222 1.00000 0.98413 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97826 1.00000      NA 0.97590 1.00000 0.11321      NA 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.94286 0.97222 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98701 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000      NA 1.00000 0.90385 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98507 0.92593 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98077 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.96552 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.92784 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99180 1.00000 1.00000 0.98684 1.00000 1.00000 0.98246 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98913 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97500 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.91176 0.95745 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000      NA 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98507 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.89706 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000      NA 0.94231 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98925 1.00000 0.99231 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97143 0.98824 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99454 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99286 1.00000 1.00000 0.98889 0.99213 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97674 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97945 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99237 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99107 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98214 1.00000 0.97727 1.00000 0.98611 0.98246 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.95775 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.90909 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.90323 0.97826 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98913 0.98684 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.82353 0.98000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97368 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98551 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000      NA 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99091 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98980 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.93478 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000      NA 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97500 0.98039 0.98649 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98592 1.00000 0.98571 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99254 1.00000 0.98824 1.00000 1.00000 0.98667 1.00000 0.98507 1.00000 1.00000 0.91071 1.00000 0.96429 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97674 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98925 1.00000 1.00000 0.97938 1.00000 0.99306 0.98837 0.87500 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99029 1.00000 1.00000 0.97727 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.96774 0.93651 1.00000 1.00000 0.98039 1.00000 0.86301 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99415 0.98684 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.94667 1.00000 0.96552 0.99367 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.92771 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.93333 1.00000 0.99495 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.85915 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99020 1.00000 0.99099 0.96970 1.00000 0.98387 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98889 0.99010 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99510 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99107 1.00000 0.99000 0.96386 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99329 1.00000 0.99390 1.00000 1.00000 0.99180 1.00000 1.00000 0.94643 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.96552 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99065 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98675 1.00000 0.98990 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97959 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99160 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98718 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99099 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99145 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98649 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99259 0.97203 1.00000 0.96067 0.98750 1.00000 0.96842 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.96296 1.00000 1.00000 0.92857 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.96689 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99138 1.00000 1.00000      NA 1.00000 0.96703 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.82222 0.95161 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98438 0.99194 1.00000 0.95833 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99254 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99048 1.00000 1.00000 0.97087 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.93182 1.00000 0.98551 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.91837 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99351 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99254 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97143 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97761 0.99000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97917 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.94709 0.99074 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.98413 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97806 1.00000 1.00000 0.99213 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99320 0.99010 1.00000 0.94521 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.97802 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000 0.99174
chr1_17742_17602_WASH7P_3p  ENSG00000227232.4   0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00610 0.00000 0.00000 0.01176 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01282 0.00000 0.00000 0.00990 0.01176 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02703 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00862 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00442 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01333 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00847 0.04167 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01250 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00629 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02222 0.00000 0.00000 0.01205 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02632 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01786 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02564 0.03333 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01681 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00552 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00787 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02632 0.00000 0.04000 0.01786 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.03030 0.00585 0.00000 0.10000 0.00870 0.01099 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00714 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01333 0.09524 0.00000 0.00467 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00671 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00637 0.00000 0.00000 0.11111 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000      NA 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01205 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01190 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01010 0.00000 0.00000 0.01538 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01389 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00521 0.00000 0.00000 0.00629 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00725 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00685 0.02564 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00532 0.00794 0.00000 0.00935 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00862 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00704 0.00775 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.03704 0.00775 0.00000 0.00667 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00943 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00917 0.00000 0.00000 0.05556 0.00000 0.00000 0.02632 0.00833 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02174 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01754 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01235 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01136 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00935 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00781 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00568 0.00000 0.00000 0.01163 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01351 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01449 0.00000 0.02041 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01235 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01316 0.00000 0.01064 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00746 0.01282 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02041 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000      NA 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02273 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01235 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00654 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01020 0.00000 0.00826 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01190 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00730 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00690 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01818 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00990 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01942 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01639 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00962 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00637 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01493 0.00000 0.00943 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01190 0.00769 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00503 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02222 0.00000 0.00000 0.00917 0.01031 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.03297 0.00752 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01087 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01235 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01220 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00366 0.01887 0.00000 0.01176 0.01887 0.00000 0.00000 0.00625 0.00000 0.00685 0.00000 0.00995 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00549 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01053 0.01587 0.00000 0.00000 0.00763 0.00000 0.00000 0.00488 0.02222 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02041 0.00000 0.03704 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000      NA 0.00000 0.00000 0.00472 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02198 0.00000 0.01042 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00446 0.00490 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01156 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01613 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00476 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01205 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00800 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00730 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.04688 0.00000 0.00000 0.01887 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00870 0.00909 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01695 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00669 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00930 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00568 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01600 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01042 0.00893 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02128 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00833 0.00000 0.00000 0.01429 0.00000 0.01695 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01818 0.02703 0.00000 0.00000 0.04167 0.00000 0.00000 0.01075 0.00000 0.00000 0.00840 0.00000 0.02941 0.00000 0.00000 0.00575 0.00000 0.00746 0.00870 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00543 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00971 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01695 0.00000 0.00410 0.00000 0.00000 0.00763 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00488 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01818 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00223 0.00000 0.00645 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00450 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00806 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00870
chr1_17504_17498_WASH7P_3p  ENSG00000227232.4   0.01674 0.00000 0.01235 0.00000 0.02381 0.02857 0.03247 0.01562 0.03000 0.01835 0.01322 0.01282 0.04762 0.02857 0.00000 0.04839 0.00000 0.03774 0.02198 0.01493 0.00000 0.03261 0.04167 0.01000 0.01190 0.02381 0.00000 0.00000 0.02632 0.02913 0.04494 0.00000 0.03774 0.04000 0.04167 0.00000 0.03529 0.02597 0.02381 0.00000 0.01031 0.03774 0.00000 0.06557 0.05096 0.00000 0.04265 0.04878 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00833 0.01626 0.03636 0.03636 0.00893 0.06061 0.00746 0.00000 0.02174 0.00862 0.01075 0.01984 0.03067 0.04673 0.04494 0.00000 0.01786 0.02564 0.00000 0.03846 0.01351 0.00000 0.04000 0.01176 0.00000 0.03623 0.00000 0.05000 0.02778 0.02105 0.00000 0.00730 0.00000 0.02632 0.02273 0.44828 0.03846 0.01333 0.01575 0.00000 0.04651 0.00000 0.00000 0.02632 0.04217 0.02247 0.00000 0.00690 0.02762 0.00000 0.02128 0.00000 0.03125 0.01163 0.00000 0.00000 0.02793 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.05714 0.05063 0.02817 0.05970 0.00000 0.00000 0.01724 0.00000 0.02752 0.03636 0.00000 0.00000 0.02222 0.00000 0.02222 0.03333 0.01124 0.01316 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00935 0.02222 0.03252 0.03509 0.00877 0.00000 0.00000 0.04054 0.01724 0.03571 0.00957 0.01020 0.01370 0.00000 0.00546 0.08475 0.02817 0.00000 0.00781 0.02632 0.01099 0.01031 0.01087 0.01724 0.02299 0.02381 0.05000 0.01449 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01935 0.00000 0.02778 0.01648 0.01111 0.00000 0.03333 0.03093 0.03704 0.03030 0.04233 0.00000 0.00699 0.05405 0.01481 0.00855 0.01667 0.00847 0.02174 0.00000 0.11111 0.04762 0.03448 0.03333 0.00000 0.02105 0.03175 0.06522 0.01613 0.01667 0.00000 0.00000 0.01212 0.00000 0.00000 0.02479 0.00000 0.00000 0.00662 0.02740 0.03797 0.03226 0.01852 0.02242 0.00000 0.03448 0.03922 0.04225 0.00000 0.02222 0.00000 0.04403 0.00000 0.02128 0.00935 0.00000 0.03067 0.02326 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00877 0.00000      NA 0.00000 0.01786 0.00893 0.08889 0.00935 0.00000 0.00000 0.03371 0.01942 0.00000 0.03947 0.05970 0.02542 0.02667 0.01961 0.03279 0.01961 0.03419 0.00476 0.01471 0.00000 0.01351 0.10465 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02913 0.01408 0.02564 0.00752 0.00000 0.01852 0.04167 0.02410 0.00000 0.03750 0.06250 0.02030 0.03627 0.00000 0.03812 0.03659 0.00000 0.03974 0.02055 0.00000 0.02479 0.02941 0.02614 0.02500 0.00000 0.00885 0.04444 0.03604 0.02041 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01515 0.00000 0.01442 0.00901 0.07143 0.01205 0.05128 0.00000 0.01111 0.00000 0.01130 0.04605 0.04082 0.05732 0.03650 0.02105 0.00000 0.00851 0.00952 0.01724 0.00000 0.05882 0.03727 0.03974 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01667 0.05263 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.11765 0.06849 0.01163 0.00000 0.04167 0.00000 0.00000 0.01739 0.01176 0.04724 0.00000 0.00000 0.04225 0.02500 0.01587 0.00000 0.00980 0.00000 0.05063 0.01282 0.01449 0.03922 0.02083 0.02752 0.04918 0.03750 0.02222 0.00000 0.01471 0.02439 0.00000 0.05319 0.03125 0.02609 0.00000 0.01724 0.02362 0.00000 0.02941 0.00513 0.05051 0.00000 0.02553 0.01744 0.05128 0.00000 0.00000 0.02381 0.01695 0.04762 0.00000 0.02198 0.00000 0.01527 0.01299 0.00000 0.00719 0.00962 0.02000 0.00000 0.05556 0.00847 0.00606 0.00000 0.01399 0.01163 0.00000 0.03390 0.00559 0.02000 0.01744 0.01064 0.01190 0.06452 0.02703 0.00813 0.00000 0.00000 0.02597 0.00000 0.00000 0.03061 0.00000 0.01299 0.02062 0.00000 0.03947 0.00000 0.15517 0.03030 0.05000 0.01163 0.00000 0.09524 0.04651 0.04878 0.00000 0.05000 0.00000 0.02959 0.02857 0.02174 0.00741 0.00709 0.03960 0.01250 0.00000 0.05882 0.00000 0.02210 0.01471 0.00000 0.03472 0.00000 0.00000 0.01389 0.01471 0.04054 0.00000 0.00000 0.04587 0.01299 0.10256 0.02614 0.00000 0.03226 0.02273 0.02564 0.01538 0.03333 0.03390 0.05941 0.00000      NA 0.02174 0.01639 0.05769 0.00000 0.03125 0.14286 0.02222 0.02273 0.00000 0.01299 0.00000 0.00000 0.06897 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.02083 0.01205 0.03636 0.02027 0.01869 0.01739 0.00000 0.00000 0.03390 0.04167 0.00000 0.00000 0.02564 0.01724 0.00000 0.01449 0.04918 0.03226 0.01220 0.00833 0.00000 0.02532 0.02500 0.00873 0.00746 0.01953 0.00935 0.03529 0.00893 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.03571 0.01402 0.10000 0.01961 0.03226 0.00000 0.00000 0.02740 0.00980 0.03727 0.00000 0.01250 0.01613 0.00000 0.00000 0.04065 0.02299 0.01754 0.01754 0.02857 0.04054 0.04839 0.00000 0.00000 0.02778 0.04651 0.02381 0.05952 0.03896 0.00699 0.00000 0.08451 0.05556 0.01481 0.01274 0.01538 0.04124 0.03571 0.09524 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.01724 0.05618 0.00000 0.03226 0.01587 0.01887 0.00000 0.00000 0.02646 0.01724 0.07059 0.04688 0.04918 0.01220 0.03488 0.00719 0.01190 0.01875 0.02963 0.00000 0.01282 0.00000 0.01869 0.05882 0.04167 0.00000 0.00000 0.02632 0.00000 0.01255 0.04000 0.02778 0.03030 0.01176 0.00000 0.02985 0.02885 0.06383 0.10000 0.00885 0.00500 0.01852 0.01961 0.02033 0.01807 0.00000 0.02564 0.02247 0.03676 0.00000 0.00000 0.01802 0.06452 0.00000 0.00000 0.02410 0.02532 0.03448 0.00000 0.02857 0.07895 0.00000 0.02703 0.00000 0.00000 0.00885 0.01587 0.02597 0.00000 0.01266 0.01613 0.01124 0.00483 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.06422 0.00000 0.01389 0.02247 0.01786 0.02941 0.01667 0.00641 0.00000 0.01515 0.03158 0.04286 0.00000 0.01316 0.02632 0.01961 0.00000 0.04054 0.01471 0.03297 0.00000 0.02041 0.01562 0.02083 0.00000 0.02500 0.01149 0.02667 0.07143 0.03333 0.01418 0.01282 0.01695 0.01176 0.00633 0.03030 0.08333 0.01429 0.01190 0.00000 0.01000 0.01481 0.01266 0.03361 0.02532 0.00000 0.00000 0.02439 0.03759 0.01613 0.04598 0.00000 0.00000 0.00541 0.01205 0.01613 0.07353 0.00000 0.00725 0.01667 0.00000 0.05263 0.01852 0.01282 0.05085 0.02410 0.02083 0.01282 0.00000 0.00971 0.01754 0.00000 0.02609 0.01786 0.03333 0.02128 0.02000 0.00830 0.03333 0.03297 0.00521 0.01515 0.00000 0.02564 0.02128 0.01515 0.00833 0.03153 0.04000 0.00671 0.00000 0.05128 0.03846 0.04225 0.03030 0.05357 0.00000 0.00000 0.01905 0.01592 0.01449 0.00000 0.03093 0.07812 0.00000 0.00000 0.04000 0.00000 0.01295      NA 0.00000 0.02905 0.02294 0.00000 0.03509 0.02273 0.00000 0.04348 0.04494 0.07692 0.00000 0.01538 0.02667 0.01087 0.00787 0.02941 0.00000 0.00645 0.00980 0.00676 0.00000 0.00000 0.05882 0.02041 0.02381 0.02963 0.01181 0.01852 0.00000 0.00000 0.02273 0.00787 0.00000 0.00000 0.00893 0.02564 0.00000 0.00000 0.01149 0.05369 0.02500 0.04255 0.01481 0.00000 0.01143 0.00000 0.02778 0.00532 0.00000 0.00000 0.01176 0.03150 0.00000 0.02083 0.00952 0.02740 0.01724 0.00000 0.01235 0.05618 0.04469 0.04615 0.00000 0.02500 0.00000 0.00787 0.00000 0.07000 0.01361 0.03636 0.01961 0.03261 0.01538 0.07692 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.04202 0.01709 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.06000 0.02339 0.02456 0.06164 0.02247 0.00000 0.02459 0.01515 0.03571 0.00000 0.01818 0.00645 0.05674 0.02878 0.01724 0.02609 0.00000 0.01351 0.02837 0.00000 0.02970 0.06579 0.03333 0.00000 0.02239 0.05556 0.00885 0.01303 0.03182 0.02000 0.03670 0.04762 0.03125 0.02778 0.03297 0.01980 0.00000 0.02703 0.01508 0.04046 0.02454 0.02778 0.02920 0.01667 0.01136 0.01639 0.00725 0.03030 0.00758 0.02326 0.01869 0.00787 0.00000 0.02041 0.00870 0.06061 0.02308 0.03876 0.01000 0.01471 0.03333 0.03704 0.03846 0.01042 0.03333 0.01299 0.03488 0.03200 0.05660 0.03704 0.00000 0.03125 0.00000 0.03165 0.00000 0.01190 0.00000 0.03448 0.09756 0.01887 0.02370 0.03846 0.08333 0.04000 0.03093 0.06742 0.00000 0.02419 0.00498 0.02857 0.00971 0.04000 0.03141 0.02667 0.03472 0.02128 0.00000 0.00000 0.06557 0.04110 0.06667 0.02817 0.00000 0.09091 0.04082 0.04478 0.04286 0.01802 0.05882 0.04839 0.00000 0.07018 0.02400 0.02326 0.02752 0.01149 0.00000 0.00000 0.04098 0.00000 0.01796 0.01793 0.00000 0.02041 0.02222 0.00000 0.00000 0.00000 0.08871 0.01442 0.00546 0.02027 0.00000 0.03659 0.00000 0.01869 0.00000 0.02000 0.02020 0.00000 0.00000 0.02083 0.00000 0.00000 0.03509 0.00000 0.04839 0.05769 0.04478 0.02597 0.00000 0.00000 0.04545 0.02586 0.01961 0.00000 0.04054 0.01695 0.00000 0.04000 0.05000 0.01124 0.04651 0.00813 0.03008 0.02597 0.00000 0.04082 0.01987 0.01931 0.00000 0.01911 0.02308 0.02400 0.02941 0.00000 0.01786 0.02857 0.01709 0.03390 0.00662 0.00690 0.00000 0.00000 0.04372 0.02381 0.02344 0.02857 0.02459 0.01087 0.04545 0.01869 0.02410 0.01136 0.04762 0.01031 0.00000 0.00000
```

Table definition:

https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/3b7y

How can I import it?

Comment: Most of these `NA` are not separated by tabs, is that intended? What is the table definition? It would be interesting to see the previous lines as well.

Comment: This file is coming from a source file, so I don't know if it was intended - https://data.broadinstitute.org/ccle/CCLE_RNAseq_ExonUsageRatio_20180929.gct.gz

Comment: Added a couple of different lines from source.

Comment: Added table definition here - https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/3b7y

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import this file.

Every table row has to fit into a single 8 kB block, and your row doesn't. PostgreSQL stores `text` columns out of line in a TOAST table to reduce the size, but even so your row is too large.

You either have to split the data into several tables (but then you won't be able to  load them with `COPY`), or you have to rebuild PostgreSQL from source with a bigger block size. That would be

```sh
./configure --with-blocksize=16
```

But be warned that few people do that, so you might find some bugs that way.

Comment: That's too bad. I wished there was an alternative.

Comment: Tables with that many columns are a problem in any case. You could consider lumping the attributes that will not be used inside the database into a `jsonb` column.

Comment: As this data is coming from an external source, I need to first import it into postgres as is. Then we need to do the analysis of which one would be useful.

Comment: @dang: you could import each line into a single `text` column and then e.g. convert the numbers to an array or a single JSON value.

Comment: can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try Citus Columnar Storage (https://github.com/citusdata/citus/tree/main/src/backend/columnar) - it's an open source extension to PG12.

My short tests showed that it can store records over 20kB (comparing to 8160B for default PG heap storage).